# How to access the reset password mailable in the new version of laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to use the reset password mailable for my project but I do not know how to access it in laravel 6.1

Here is my method

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'address_id' => 'required',
            'name'=> 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'POBox' =>['required', 'min:6', 'max:6'],
            'role_id' => 'required',
        ]);

        $quickpass = substr( str_shuffle( str_repeat( 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', 10 ) ), 0, 10 );
        $newuser = User::create([
            'address_id' =>$request->address_id,
            'name'=> $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'POBox'=> $request->POBox,
            'password' => Hash::make($quickpass),
            'role_id' => $request->role_id,
        ]);
        Mail::to($newuser->email)
            ->send( );

        return view('admin.index')->with('message','The user has been created and a password reset email has been sent to them.');

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Notification used is `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword`. It builds a `MailMessage` inline.

The `PasswordBroker` can be used to create the token and send off the notification for you. The method `sendResetLink` will take an array of credentials to find the User by.

`Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker`

```
$resp = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::broker()->sendResetLink([
    'email' => '...',
]);
```

Comment: I donot understand 'email' line

Comment: its the email address to find the user by

Comment: Now this is the new error I am getting "App\Http\Controllers\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password' not found"

Comment: namespacing .... alias the class or reference it via FQCN `\Illuminate\Support....`

Comment: Sorry I am still new to laravel. How to namespace  allias or FQCN. Can I just get an example according to my code please

Comment: `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::broker()->....`  the ` \ ` at the start of the class reference

Comment: the alias is the same way you are able to use `User` or `Mail`